# Using UART to check data receiving from SPH0645 Mic I2S protocol

Tags: c, audio, stm32, microphone, adafruit

I'm trying to interface these SPH0645 Mics (I2S) to a STM32f767ZI board.

I have wired it correctly, now just trying to test the mic by passing the data through UART to my pc. Hoping someone can point me in the correct direction.

I have tried passing straight to the UART transmit. However I think I may need some datahandling - I am receiving from the UART, but sometimes just 0 or other times just gibberish which is not from the Mic as it still transmits even when i disconnect the mic.

I2S mic is receiving data in 24 bits in 32 bit frame, the last 8 bits are junk. The protocol is Big Endian, I am thinking that the HAL library handles this, however I am not completely sure.

```
uint16_t data;
while (1)
 {
/* USER CODE END WHILE */
HAL_StatusTypeDef result= HAL_I2S_Receive(&hi2s1,&data,2,100);

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,&data,2,100);
/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
 }
/* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the return value of `HAL_I2S_Receive(&hi2s1, &data, 1, 100)`
2. Did you verify `HAL_I2S_Receive` expects `uint32_t*` as 2nd argument? I think it shall expect `uint16_t*`
3. Using `HAL_UART_Transmit` you want to transmit the data over UART. Shouldn't you pass `data` as an argument to `HAL_UART_Transmit` ?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally displayed a test code which was going to test if the UART transmit worked. - It successfully transmits 'storage' , I have edited my question to reflect my mistake.